# Spring boot and react running on tomcat

Tags: javascript, spring, reactjs, tomcat, web-deployment

I am developing Spring boot application with react client using gradle. I am new to all these technologies.
Currently I am able to create war file which includes following folders:

- META-INF
- public (contains build of client part - index.html, index.js and other .js scripts)
- WEB-INF (contains compiled spring boot backend app)

Currently, after deploying war to tomcat, I am able to access client static content on http://localhost:8080/app-name/public/. Also I am able to access routes defined in spring controllers on http:// localhost:8080/app-name/route (these are just for testing purposes, I want this commands to be accessed only through REST calls from client).

Now, what I want is make that static client content available under route http://localhost:8080/app-name/xxx-yyy/public

I don't know what is right way to do this (actually, only way I know is create xxx-yyy subfolder on tomcat a put public folder inside it. I think this is bad approach). Other way would be somehow forward from spring controller but I am not able to do that.

It is possible that this is bad concept and I should make it other way. I would be glad for any suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? Because with Spring Boot the Tomcat server is embedded into a JAR file, so, you won't be working with WARs.

Comment: basically you want to bind your controller actions with reactjs?

Comment: @lbpeppers I am not using the embedded Tomcat server. My company wants deploy it on their own tomcat in docker. So I have to work with WAR.

Comment: @VikramSaini Yes, if it is possible with my current structure of WAR file (or suggestion what should in it)

Comment: i can help you with JAR and not with WAR.why are you  working with WAR's?

Comment: I will just expose a REST service to be consumed by the React client. This will bring you scalability. What if your company wants to move to Angular2 after a couple of months? Binding your code now to Angular? That's time-consuming.

Comment: @FilipVelemínský I see you asked this a long time ago. I am in the same situation as you were before. Could you please answer me how did you solve it? I want to run Spring boot + ReactJS on external Tomcat server 9.xx

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using create-react-app.

For production deployment, the React application consists of static files only. These files are generated with create-react-app : `npm run build`. Cf. the official docs about [deployment](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment).

So you just have to serve these static files in your Spring Boot app, for instance in the folder `src/main/resources/static`. Here is the documentation about [static content in Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

At the end, Tomcat will run dynamic REST web services (for instance at `/api`) and React files.

Note: if you are using Spring Security, make sure that React files such as index.html are publicly available.